# Find letter of text with each text

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I want find a string in text and loop it and getting first characters before it string by jquery.

My text is as:(EX)

> 1111111010011001011001100111111111010011100111010001011110011101000100010110010101000011111000011110100101010111111010010011111

And i want find this `1110100` in it whit loop each it

result is as:

> 1 1 0 0 1 1

How is it?

Comment: seems the question is written in machine code.. ;)     explain a bit more

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regexp and use the `replace` method over your string to collect the chars that appear before each occurrence of your searched string.

```
let a ="1111111010011001011001100111111111010011100111010001011110011101000100010110010101000011111000011110100101010111111010010011111";

let matches = []
a.replace(/([01])1110100/g,(_,charbefore)=>{
 matches.push(charbefore);
});
console.log(matches);
```

returns `[ "1", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1" ]`

Comment: tanx, if search this: `11111`, in first text there is nothing but it give me `1`. !? see: http://jsfiddle.net/58cw910s/

Comment: Code in jsfiddle gives the correct result : [ "1", "0", "0", "0", "0" ]